# Java While loop database

Tags: java, mysql, while-loop

I have two loops in the code shown below. The problem is that the first loop iterates only once. It doesn't display all the data.

```
st = conn.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from geopools");           
while(rs.next()){
   System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
   rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from Geofields where id_pool='"+rs.getInt("id")+"'");
   while (rs.next()) {
         System.out.println(rs.getString("name")+"//");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you use the same `ResultSet`. Use a separate `ResultSet` for the second iteration:

```
st = conn.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from geopools");           
while(rs.next()){
   System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
   ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from Geofields where id_pool='"+rs.getInt("id")+"'");
   while (rs2.next()) {
         System.out.println(rs2.getString("name")+"//");
   }
}
```

Comment: When You add another loop then also use a separate ResultSet again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your second loop consumes the `ResultSet`.

Imagine you are looping from `1` to `10`:

```
int i = 1;
for(; i <= 10; ++i) {
    doStuff();
}
```

It should be obvious that `doStuff()` is executed `10` times. Now we change that to your loop:

```
int i = 1;
for(; i <= 10; ++i) {
    doStuff();
    for(; i <= 10; ++i) {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

Now `doStuff` is executed **once**, then we enter the inner loop. That executes `10` times and increments `i`. When the inner loop exits, `i` is `11` and the outer loop condition is met, it exits immediately.

You are doing (almost) *exactly* the same thing, instead of `i` you have a `ResultSet` which has a number of rows. The first loop takes one row, and prints the `id` from that row. Then the inner loop consumes the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

it works very well, but when I added a third loop I get the same problem and this is my source code:

```
st = conn.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from geopools");   
int idPool=0;
int idField =0;
while(rs.next()){
     DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Pool : "+rs.getString("name"));
     poolNode.add(treeNode);
     idPool = rs.getInt("id");

     st2 = conn.createStatement();
     rs2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT * from Geofields where id_pool='"+idPool+"'");
     while (rs2.next()) {                    
          DefaultMutableTreeNode fieldsNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Field : "+rs2.getString("name"));
          treeNode.add(fieldsNode);
          idField = rs2.getInt("id");

          st3 = conn.createStatement();
          rs3 = st3.executeQuery("SELECT * from geofieldsproject where id_pool='"+idPool+"'");
          while (rs3.next()) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode projectsNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Field : "+rs3.getString("name"));
                treeNode.add(projectsNode);                    
           }  
     }
 }            

 st = null;
 rs = null;
 st2 = null;
 rs2 = null;
 st3 = null;
 rs3 = null;
```